# Protobuf equivalent to JWK

Tags: protocol-buffers, jwk

JWK is a handy standard, but it has a lot of intrinsic overhead: string parsing, base64 encoding, etc. Is there a protobuf equivalent? Bonus points if it's on a standards track!

I've come across [tink](https://github.com/google/tink) which seems to have some such functionality, but being a JWK substitute is clearly not its main purpose.

Comment: There isn't a standardized one, but the one you linked can be used as a guidance. Proto generally required less standardization because of already unambiguous protocol definition. Side note, we are working on a spec that would bring in JOSE over to Protobuf, and I'm curious what direction you have taken in your project.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski that spec sounds interesting! I've not had the bandwidth to pursue this so for now I'm just using serialised JWKs as strings in my protobuf. I do hope to swap out to something more direct & efficient